# supply a matching data structure that supports MakeEmpty, Insert and DeleteFreq

Tags: data-structures

I've been struggling with solving the following question:

`Supply an ADT that stores members (not necessarily unique) and supports the following functionalities:
1) MakeEmpty - creates an empty data structure - complexity in time Θ(1) worst case
2) Insert - inserts a member into the data structure - complexity Θ(1) in average case
3) DeleteFreq - gets out the most frequent member from the data structure (the member exists the maximal number of times in the data structure) - time complexity Θ(log(n) in worst case`

At the beginning I was thinking about using a hash table (because of the average time of Insert function) and the hash-table based on keys of the members. In addition, for each cell in the hash-table I thought about holding a pointer to AVL/2-3 Search Tree.

But then, I'm thinking it's possibly not correct because only hash-table initialization (all pointers to NULL) gonna cost Θ(hash-table-size). Furthermore, Insert function could be much more expensive if the load factor isn't good.

I would appreciate your advice and guiding

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  You can use the standard trick of starting with a small hash table, and double the size of the hashtable each time the large factor exceeds some small constant threshold.  This involves creating a new array & rehashing all items whenever you do that, but it's rare enough that the amortized cost is $O(1)$.  But how are you going to support insert in $O(1)$ time?  Each insert will have to update the search tree, right?  What's the cost of that?  Maybe think about the approach a bit more, then edit the question accordingly?

Comment: Is this a homework, quiz, or exam question for you?

Comment: @jbapple It was an exam question that I couldn't solve. though it really interests me how to solve it.

Comment: @D.W. In this scenario - I can't see how deleteFreq takes Θ(log(n))... it's gonna take Θ(1) in average... Furthermore, If I reallocate a new array each time load factor is too big then in each time I should reallocate the table as twice as bigger. Secondly, I think that the insert to the hash table should also update the frequently of the member in it (let's say the hashTable would be a 2D array -first column for keys and second column for the frequency of the frequent member in the key. Last but not least, I don't really know what to do with the search trees, I'm not even sure If I need them.

Comment: You are right, you do not need search trees.

Answer (score 1):

"""

This file is both Markdown and Python.

We keep the keys in two data structures. One is a
doubly-linked list, like this:

```
| <- [] <-> [] <-> [] <-> [] -> |
```

Here, `[]` is a node and `|` is None. Pointers are one-way
(`->`) or two-way (`<->`).

Instead of being terminated by null pointers, the list
will be terminated by nodes that point to themselves. An
empty list looks like this:

```
[o] <-> [o]
```

Here `[o]` is a node that points to itself. These nodes
are called "sentinals".

Nodes keep two other pieces of data. The first is a set of
keys. The second is a `frequency`, which represents the
number of times each of those keys is in the multiset. For
instance, If you insert `a` twice and `b` seven times and
`c` seven times, there is a node in the list with
`frequency` set to 7 and the set of keys `{b, c}`.

```
[o] <-> [7, {b,c}] <-> [3, {a}] <-> [o]
```

The other invariants that are maintained:

- The nodes are stored in frequency order
- The sentinal at the high-frequency end has frequency
  None
- The sentinal at the low-frequency end has frequency 0
- No node has negative frequency
- No two nodes have the same frequency
- The sentinals have empty key sets, but no other nodes
  have empty key sets

So:

```
"""
class FreqBucket(object):
  def __init__(self, lo, hi, freq):
    self.lo = lo
    self.hi = hi
    self.freq = freq
    self.kids = set()

  def __repr__(self):
    return ("FreqBucket({}, {}, {}, {})"
            .format(self.lo.freq, self.hi.freq,
                    self.freq, self.kids))

  def unlink(self, key):
    """Remove key and remove self from the list if necessary"""
    if key in self.kids: self.kids.remove(key)
    if not self.kids:
      self.hi.lo = self.lo
      self.lo.hi = self.hi

  def increase(self, key):
    """Increase the frequency of the given key from this node"""
    result = self.hi
    if self.hi.freq != self.freq + 1:
      # There is no FreqBucket with the right .freq, so we
      # must make a new one:
      old_hi = self.hi
      self.hi = FreqBucket(self, self.hi, self.freq + 1)
      old_hi.lo = self.hi
      result = self.hi
    # Move the key to the next FreqBucket:
    result.kids.add(key)
    self.unlink(key)
    return result
"""
```

TallPoppies uses the list of FreqBuckets described
above. It keeps a map in which each key in the structure
maps to its corresponding FreqBucket.

```
"""
class TallPoppies(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # The keys of the self.keys dictionary are the inserted
    # objects; the values are FreqBuckets.
    self.keys = {}
    # Make the sentinels and link them to each other and
    # themselves. We need mini for inserts and maxi for
    # deletes.
    self.mini = FreqBucket(None, None, 0)
    self.mini.lo = self.mini
    self.maxi = FreqBucket(None, None, None)
    self.maxi.lo = self.mini
    self.maxi.hi = self.maxi
    self.mini.hi = self.maxi

  def __repr__(self):
    return ("TallPoppies({}, {}, {})"
            .format(self.keys, self.mini, self.maxi))

  def insert(self, key):
    if key in self.keys:
      self.keys[key] = self.keys[key].increase(key)
    else:
      self.keys[key] = self.mini.increase(key)

  def delete_freq(self):
    result = self.maxi.lo.kids.pop()
    self.maxi.lo.unlink(result)
    del self.keys[result]
    return result
```

`insert` and `delete_freq` take expected amortized O(1) time. You need hash tables and linked lists, but not search trees.